# jQuery collapsable function menu from JSON not show all sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery collapsable function. All data menu getting from JSON.
You can check the demo below.

My question, for example Project 1 has 3 menus, but why when I click on that it's only show 1 menu?

Any idea how to solve it?

```js
var abc = [
{
project: {
  projectName: 'Project 1',
},
module: [{
  moduleName: "A"
},
{
  moduleName: "B"
},
{
  moduleName: "C"
}]
},
{
project: {
  projectName: 'Project 2'
},
module: [{
  moduleName: "D"
}]
},
{
project: {
  projectName: 'Project 3'
},
module: [{
  moduleName: "E"
},
{
  moduleName: "F"
}]
}];

for(var i=0; i<abc.length; i++) {
    var menu = '<dt><div class="icon"><i class="fa-regular fa-server"></i></div><div class="menu-name">' + abc[i].project.projectName + '</div><span class="more"><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i></span></dt>'; 

    for(var j=0; j<abc[i].module.length; j++) {

      menu += '<dd><a href="">' + abc[i].module[j].moduleName + '</a></dd>';


    }
    ;

    $(".collapsable").append(menu);

  }
  
  
  var speed = 200;
$('dt.expanded + dd').slideDown(speed);

$('dt').on('click', function () {
  var that = $(this);


  // Expandable
  if (that.parent().hasClass('expandable')) {

    that.toggleClass('expanded').next('dd').slideToggle(speed);

    // Collapsable
  } else if (that.parent().hasClass('collapsable')) {

    if (!that.hasClass('expanded')) {
      that.siblings('dt').removeClass('expanded').next('dd').slideUp(speed);
    }

    that.toggleClass('expanded').next('dd').slideToggle(speed);
    // Standard
  } else {
    // make sure its not collapsing itself and reappearing right after.
    if (!that.hasClass('expanded')) {

      that.siblings('dt').removeClass('expanded').next('dd').slideUp(speed);
      that.toggleClass('expanded').next('dd').slideToggle(speed);
    }
  }


});
```

```css
dd {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<dl class="collapsable">
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a `<p>` tag around the `<dd>` tag.
.next( function only selects the first `dd` element

```js
var abc = [
{
project: {
  projectName: 'Project 1',
},
module: [{
  moduleName: "A"
},
{
  moduleName: "B"
},
{
  moduleName: "C"
}]
},
{
project: {
  projectName: 'Project 2'
},
module: [{
  moduleName: "D"
}]
},
{
project: {
  projectName: 'Project 3'
},
module: [{
  moduleName: "E"
},
{
  moduleName: "F"
}]
}];

for(var i=0; i<abc.length; i++) {
    var menu = '<dt><div class="icon"><i class="fa-regular fa-server"></i></div><div class="menu-name">' + abc[i].project.projectName + '</div><span class="more"><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i></span></dt>'; 
menu +='<dd>';
    for(var j=0; j<abc[i].module.length; j++) {

      menu += '<p><a href="">' + abc[i].module[j].moduleName + '</a></p>';


    }
    menu +='</dd>';

    $(".collapsable").append(menu);

  }
  
  
  var speed = 200;
$('dt.expanded + dd').slideDown(speed);

$('dt').on('click', function () {
  var that = $(this);


  // Expandable
  if (that.parent().hasClass('expandable')) {

    that.toggleClass('expanded').next('dd').slideToggle(speed);

    // Collapsable
  } else if (that.parent().hasClass('collapsable')) {

    if (!that.hasClass('expanded')) {
      that.siblings('dt').removeClass('expanded').next('dd').slideUp(speed);
    }

    that.toggleClass('expanded').next('dd').slideToggle(speed);
    // Standard
  } else {
    // make sure its not collapsing itself and reappearing right after.
    if (!that.hasClass('expanded')) {

      that.siblings('dt').removeClass('expanded').next('dd').slideUp(speed);
      that.toggleClass('expanded').next('dd').slideToggle(speed);
    }
  }


});
```

```css
dd {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<dl class="collapsable">
</dl>
```